# how to call controller action ononchange event of datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails, datepicker

Hi I have custom datepicker and I want to calculate something on the onchange event of year.

the code below does not work on onchange. I also tried onchange and call javasript function like this `onchange='toggleTextAreaForTypeOfDischarge(name);'` but the result is messed up. Like it calls the 'toggleTextAreaForTypeOfDischarge() on year drop down population. So if there's 100 years, it will call it 100 times and it will not call it upon actual selection of year.

```
<g:icmDatePicker name="enteredIntoServiceDate" precision="day" default="none" value="${activeReserveDutyServiceInstance?.enteredIntoServiceDate}" noSelection="['': 'Select...']"   years="${dateRange }" yearSortOrder="desc"onchange="${remoteFunction(action:'getCityAndState', controller:'postcode',params:'\'zipcode=\' + this.value, onSuccess:'getCityAndState(data,\'i11\',\'i12\')')}"/>
```

I was able to make the event work like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select[id ^= enteredIntoServiceDate_year], select[id ^= enteredIntoServiceDate_month], select[id ^= enteredIntoServiceDate_day]").change(function (){
       checkPeriodOfwarAccdgToDate()
    });


 });

function checkPeriodOfwarAccdgToDate()
{
    alert("test")

}
</script>
```

but my problem is I need to call the controller and action from there so I can do the calcuation in the code behind, so I inserted this inside checkPeriodOfwarAccdgToDate function but does not work.

```
$.ajax({
        alert("test")
           url: 'Postcode/GetCityAndState',
           type: 'POST',
           data: form,
        dataType: "text",
           success: function(obj){
                    alert(obj);
           }    
        });
```

Can anyone point me to right dereiction how I can call an action from a controller in the event onchange of this datepicker. thanks.

Comment: What is icmDatePicker?  You're using the Grails namespace but I don't see that datePicker as part of the Grails library.

Comment: sorry for not mentioning that. the icmdatepicker is a custom datepicker our team made.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest aproach is to use a remoteLink function that gets executed at the on change event.

Here you can have a look at the remoteLink:

[remoteLink Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteLink.html)

There you can find a easy way to use it on your jsp.

```
my link = <%= remoteLink(action: 'show', id: 1,
              update: 'success', onFailure: 'showError();')
              { "this is the link body" } %>
```

Hope it helps or gives you a hint on how to keep going.

Good luck!